# Unable to copy files from current directory to Remote directory path

Tags: c#, security, iis, remote-access

I have an application hosted in IIS server and it executes a batch file. The batch file contains few CMD command such as mkdir, xcopy etc. When I run the same application from Visual Studio, it copies all the files inside the new folder successfully. When I try to run the same application from IIS, it ends without throwing any error. The authentication used in the application is Windows and it is configured inside config file, not in internet manager.

So, below are the point of concerns:

1. While running the application, which user helps to authenticate the folder access, is that IIS user or the current user?
2. Is that access related issue or any other configuration related?
3. What is the preferable solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely it's an access issue, batch file inherits the access rights from the process which executes it, in your case it's IIS. Check IIS AppPool's PoolIdentity property to see which account/permission being used. Whatever you have configured here should have access to the folder your batch process trying to access.

Comment: Have you managed to sort your problem out ?

Answer (score 1):

1. The user that is used to authenticate the folder access is the user with whom your IIS application pool is associated
2. Without any error message it is hard to say. However it is most likely to be because of an authorization issue yes
3. What you can try is to allow access to the folder for the user that is associated with your IIS application pool and see if the problem persists

Hope it helps.